# Python Elliptic Curve word encrypter

Tags: python, math

I've recently been learning python and to kick myself off I decided to try and code a small program that encrypts a User's string/word using the Elliptic Curve Encryption method.

However I'm having issues with the loops and other certain things.

```
import math

pub = 5
priv = 19 
m = 91

word = input("word:  ")

for char in word:
enc1 = ord(char)*ord(char)
while pub > 0:
    enc2 = enc1 / m
    enc3 = math.floor(enc2)
    enc4 = enc1 - (enc3*m)
    enc1 = enc4*enc4
    print(enc4)
pub = pub-1
```

The issue I'm having above is that when I run the code it doesn't loop the way I intend it to. Which is to make `enc4` a string, such as the inputted word and restart the process for pub amount of times, thus encrypting the input string pub times.

Comment: If `enc4` is a string, what is `enc4*enc4` supposed to yield?

Comment: Is your indentation correct in the question? The `pub = pub - 1` is not part of the while.

Comment: Is the `for` loop having no body a typo or an actual bug?

Comment: I'm new to Python coding and I'm getting a lot of my resources from the Internet. I actually just looked at the pub = pub - 1 and realised it isn't in the loop either haha.

Comment: Here is what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: Here is what the code is supposed to do. Say for a letter with an ASCII code of 68. 68*68=4624, 4624 = 4624/91 then rounded to nearest 1 = 50. 91*50 = 4550. So the first iteration of the encryption is 4624-4550=74. So the new ASCII code is 74. And it repeats that process pub amount of times. And to decrypt it it uses 74 and does the process priv amount of times (priv being the private key)

Comment: So in python it should be something like.. Enc1=ord(char)*ord(char). Enc2=enc1/m. Enc3=math.floor(enc2). Enc4=enc1-(enc3*91). And then somehow I want to turn those numbers back into a word and replace the previous word so I can make a new loop instead of having an input and a for char in word loop so that the process is made simpler. But I don't know how

Comment: For some reason I can't go to a new line or do code on my iPad so sorry if its a bitch to understand

Comment: I understand there's no modular arithmetic in there because I just want to get this out of the way first and be able to make a functional encrypter with just the values in the code above. After I finish that I will go onto making the calculator of which computes the values for the encrypter